# How do I iterate a class of my creation in Java?

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

I created a class MyList that has a field

```
private LinkedList<User> list;
```

I would like to be able to iterate the list like this:

```
for(User user : myList) {
   //do something with user
}
```

(when my list is an instance of MyList).
How? What should I add to my class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
imort java.util.*;

class MyList implements Iterable<User> {
   private LinkedList<User> list; 

   ... // All of your methods

   // And now the method that allows 'for each' loops
   public Iterator<User> iterator() { return list.iterator(); }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Implement the [Iterable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface. [Here's an example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/CreatingIterableObjectsusingaforeachforlooponanIterableobject.htm) on how to use this.